# MySQL, Finding every string/words frequency in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find every word frequency in a column by using MySQL only (if possible). For example:

Table:

```
id message
1  I want to eat pizza
2  I wanted chocolates
3  He doesn't like me
```

Query: ???

Result:

Word Frequency

```
I   2 
want 1
to 1
eat 1
pizza 1
wanted 1
```

etc..

Is it possible? If so please help, thank you

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a split string command. I think this would be much better accomplished in a scripting language, such as PHP. However it's not entirely impossible as long as the number of words in the string remains very small.

Comment: @mankowitz how do you do this in php? sorry i'm not that accomplished yet in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the data.  This is a pain:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(message, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word,
       count(*) 
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5
     ) n join
     t
     on n.n <= 1 + length(message) - length(replace(message, ' ', ''))
group by word;
```

The above assumes that all messages are five words or less.  You can extend the number in the first subquery for longer messages.

Comment: i'm gonna need some time to understand the code but that worked like magic. thank you so much!

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, you have to assume all messages are 5 words or less.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php example. You will probably have to tweak it a bit.

lets assume you have a word_frequency table with a unique column `word` and an integer for `count`. Also, this is susceptible to SQL injection, so you should be careful. But this should get you started.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT message FROM table1");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
   $words = explode(" ", $row['message']);
   foreach ($words as $word) {
      mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO word_frequency (`word`,`count`) VALUES ('$word',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;");
   }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Got it, this will definitely help. Thanks!